# How to know size of header of a WAV file

Tags: filesystems

It will help to know how to figure out the size of header of a WAV file by looking at its byte structure.

[image]

Source: http://soundfile.sapp.org/doc/WaveFormat/

UPDATE:
On second look, it says SubChunkSize = 16. But not sure how 10 00 00 00 leads to 16. Now given 16 and 2 channels, it is 32. 32 + 12 bytes of earlier block (that includes RIFF, WAVE, and 4 bytes)  leads to 44?